# Android webkit proxy for HTML5 video

Tags: android, html, video, proxy, webkit

I have set a proxy for an Android webkit by using the class `android.webkit.WebViewCore` and `android.net.ProxyProperties` with reflection, and it works fine when I browse web pages.
But my browser cannot play HTML5 videos like YouTube, because the network traffic of HTML5 video doesn't go through the proxy. And my question is how to set a proxy for HTML5 videos on the Android webkit?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, proxies are not currently supported for HTML5 media: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54132